# How to use WorksheetFunction.CountIf in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, countif

I am moving my VBA code into C# VSTO Excel addin project in VS2019. One issue encountered today is the WorksheetFunction.Countif messed up the FOR loop. At the very beginning, there was an error "OleAut reported a type mismatch" popped out. Somehow, I could not repeat that error anymore. But I know the issue is still there. Please help. Thanks.
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public void Validate_Tags1()
{
    //If found the invalid data, highlight it.
    Boolean fDup = false, fSpare, fTBD = false, fSChar = false, fEmptyTag = false, fInvIOType = false, fInvTag;
    Excel.Workbook wbk = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    Excel.Worksheet wsh = wbk.Worksheets[1];
    Excel.Range rng;
    Regex keywrd;
    int intRowIO = wsh.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;
    rng.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    //Loop through each tag in the Column 3. Spare channels are filtered out. Invalid cell will be red highlighted.
    foreach (Excel.Range rngCell in rng)
    {
        string strtag = rngCell.Value2;
        //Check if the tag cell is empty
        if ((strtag is null) || (strtag == ""))
        {
            fEmptyTag = true;
            rngCell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            //Check if tag is still "To Be Determined"
            keywrd = new Regex("TBD", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Boolean fTBDTag = false;
            if (keywrd.IsMatch(strtag))
            {
                fTBD = true;
                fTBDTag = true;
                rngCell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            //Check if the tag is duplicated. 
            keywrd = new Regex("spare", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            fSpare = keywrd.IsMatch(strtag);
            if (!fSpare && !fTBDTag)
            {   listbox1.items.add("Row " + rngCell.Row + ": Found no issue.");   
                // I had to comment out the following lines to get the FOR loop completed. If put the 
                //codes back, the Messagebox on the last line won't pop out. 
                //if (ExcelApp.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, rngCell.Value2) > 1)
                //{
                //    fDup = true;
                //    rngCell.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                //}
            }
        }
    }
    messagebox.show("Done!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code shown, you are missing a declaration for `ExcelApp`

Try adding this line at the beginning of your code:

```
var ExcelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
```